# Make sure no duplicates in "parent" of parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and PHPMyAdmin, but my code is all neutral so happy to switch to Postgres or whatever, but this should be straight forward enough. I haven't designed anything yet, just after best approaches.

I have 3 database tables that describes a premises. Let's say a hotel.

This theoretical hotel has multiple venues - 2 restaurants and a bar. Each of those has a few different rooms/areas. In these rooms are tables that customers can sit at.

In SQL, I imagine the tables would look like this

| Venues |
| --- |

| Venue ID | Venue Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Restaurant 1 |
| 2 | Restaurant 2 |
| 3 | Bar |

| Rooms |
| --- |

| Room ID | Room Name | Parent Venue (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Patio | 1 |
| 2 | Function Room | 1 |
| 3 | Alcove | 3 |
| 4 | Private Dining | 2 |

| Tables |
| --- |

| Table ID | Table Name | Parent Room (foreign key) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Table 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Table 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Table 3 | 1 |
| 4 | Table 4 | 2 |
| 5 | Table 1 | 3 |
| 6 | Table 2 | 3 |
| 7 | Table 3 | 3 |
| 8 | Table 4 | 3 |
| 9 | Table 1 | 4 |
| 10 | Table 2 | 4 |
| 11 | Table 3 | 4 |

I hope that data is correct :p

What I want to do is define a relationship whereas it's impossible to add a Table Name if it already exists in that venue. It doesn't matter what room the table is in.

E.g if I was to add another "Table 4", it would succeed in being entered if it was entered into Room 4, as Room 4 belongs to Restaurant 2, which does not already have a "Table 4". However if it was entered into any other room, it would fail as Restaurant 1 and Bar already have a "Table 4" in one of their rooms.

Now in the server side code this is fairly easy to check as I can do multiple queries or joins or a myriad of other ways, however I was wondering how to do this in SQL/PhpMyAdmin directly. I'm having a bit of trouble finding my way around MyAdmin.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to redundantly include the parent venue in the tables table.  So `tables` would have the additional column:

```
venueID
```

`rooms` would have a unique constraint (which is redundant):

```
alter table rooms add constraint unq_rooms_venueId
    unique (venueId, roomId);
```

Then tables would have a unique constraint:

```
alter table tables add constraint unq_table_venueId
    unique (tableName, venueId);
```

This solves the problem without having to resort to triggers.

Comment: Yup, was my initial thinking, just didn't know if there was an easy way to do  the extra step. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshDredge . . . This is actually the "easy" way.  The alternative involve triggers.

Comment: Which I'm happy to avoid, will make as answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is switch from technical IDs to composite natural keys. You can use numbers for this (i.e. give a venue a number, a room a number, maybe a table a number) or use the names, if these are guaranteed not to change. E.g.:

```
venues
(
  venue_name,
  primary key (venue_name)
);

rooms
(
  venue_name,
  room_name,
  primary key (venue_name, room_name),
  foreign key (venue_name) references venues (venue_name)
)

tables
(
  venue_name,
  room_name,
  table_name,
  primary key (venue_name, room_name, table_name),
  foreign key (venue_name, room_name) references rooms (venue_name, room_name),
  unique constraint (venue_name, table_name)
)
```

(If using the names for keys and your tables don't contain any other information aside from the names, you can easily remove the tables `venues` and `rooms` of course and only keep the `tables` table, if you want.)

Same thing with numbers:

```
venues
(
  venue_no,
  name,
  primary key (venue_no)
);

rooms
(
  venue_no,
  room_no,
  name,
  primary key (venue_no, room_no),
  foreign key (venue_no) references venues (venue_no)
)

tables
(
  venue_no,
  room_no,
  table_no,
  name,
  primary key (venue_no, room_no, table_no),
  foreign key (venue_no, room_no) references rooms (venue_no, room_no),
  unique constraint (venue_no, name)
)
```